# How does ReactJS handle memory for an app with a large number of components?

Tags: reactjs

I'm rebuilding a traditional large scale web application in ReactJS. I'm using react-router to load different components (with child components) based on the current route. The app will have hundreds of routes, and my concern is that the application might slow down memory wise the longer the user is on the app (lots of routes visited).

Should this even be a concern, or is there something I need to do to unload previously loaded components for performance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not really a question for Stack Overflow, but only components that are actively being rendered are stored in memory. When you switch to a new route and all the components from the previous route are unmounted, they'll be cleaned up by the Javascript garbage collector. So having multiple *separate* routes that are rendered discretely is fine, the only memory/performance issue is how many thing are rendered *at the same time*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should this even be a concern, or is there something I need to do to unload previously loaded components for performance?

Not a concern at all. React has state lifecycles and most important principle which is [`Reconciliation`](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) which states:

> On the next state or props update, that render() function will return a different tree of React elements. React then needs to figure out how to efficiently update the UI to match the most recent tree.

Answer (score 0):

Also, in addition to other answers, you might be able to improve the performance of your react app using techniques such as [code splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html).

Instead of downloading the entire app bundle before users can use it, code splitting allows you to split your code into small chunks which you can then load on demand. You may introduce [Route based Code splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#route-based-code-splitting) since you have large number of routes in your application.

As mentioned in the docs:

> Code-splitting your app can help you “lazy-load” just the things that are currently needed by the user, which can dramatically improve the performance of your app. While you haven’t reduced the overall amount of code in your app, you’ve avoided loading code that the user may never need, and reduced the amount of code needed during the initial load.